# Self-centralizing subgroups of order $p^2$ in $p$-groups of maximal class

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, p-groups, nilpotent-groups

Let $G$ be a finite $p$-group. It's an old result of Suzuki that if $G$ possesses a self-centralizing subgroup of order $p^2$ then $G$ has maximal class, and in fact the converse is true. However, the proof of the converse appears not particularly easy, at least as far as I know. See Huppert, Section III.14, or Leedham-Green--McKay for definitions. I will refer to Huppert for specific results.

The only proof I know is the following: if $x\in G$ lies outside all $2$-step centralizers $K_i=C_G(\gamma_i(G)/\gamma_{i+2}(G))$ for $2\leq i\leq n-2$ then $C_G(x)$ has order $p^2$ by Huppert, III.14.13. This proof is easy, just an induction up the central series. Thus the problem is proving that not all maximal subgroups are $2$-step centralizers. If $|G|$ is small, say around $|G|\leq p^{p+1}$, then there are not enough $K_i$ for all maximal subgroups to be one of the $K_i$. If $|G|$ is large though, one appears to have to use the fact that $G$ cannot be exceptional, i.e., all $K_i$ are in fact equal (Huppert, III.14.18), or at least $G/Z(G)$ is not exceptional and hence the $K_i$ are at most two maximal subgroups (Huppert, III.14.6).

**So my question is, if one is only trying to prove the existence of self-centralizing subgroups of $p$-groups of maximal class, is there a faster way that doesn't involve using the lack of exceptionality?**

One naive approach is to use induction on $|G|$. The result holds for $G/Z(G)$, so you obtain a self-centralizing subgroup there. The preimage is a subgroup $B$ of order $p^3$, containing $Z(G)$. If this subgroup is non-abelian then any subgroup $A$ of order $p^2$ other than $Z_2(G)\leq B$ is self-centralizing. But if $B$ is abelian, this doesn't work. And I don't see why $B$ is not abelian. Equivalently, $B$ can be contained in the $2$-step stabilizer $C_G(Z_2(G))$, and I don't see how to force it not to be, or at least that there is a choice of it not being. It seems that I end up back at trying to make sure there are enough maximal subgroups that are not the $K_i$ to allow me to make a choice, but I cannot see how to do this without proving the much stronger results about exceptionality.

Comment: This cannot work. Since $B/Z$ is self-centralized, it must contain the center $T/Z$ of $G/Z$ which is of order $p$. Then $B/T=(B/Z)/(T/Z)$ is of order $p$. Hence $B/Z$ is either cyclic of order $p^2$ of $C_p\times C_p$. In the first case $B$ is Abelian of order $p^3$, in the second case it is the Heisenberg $p$-group. Clearly an Abelian $B$ of order $p^3$ cannot contain a  self-centralized subgroup of order $p^2$. So this approach cannot work.

Comment: @markvs  The theory of 2-step centralizers assures us that there is always a non-abelian choice of $B$. The question is whether you need the whole theory to prove that. I'm also not 100% sure that if $B/Z$ has exponent $p$ that $B$ is non-abelian. I don't see why it cannot be $C_{p^2}\times C_p$ or elementary abelian. I mean it cannot, but you again need some theory, unless there's an obvious trick.

Comment: The theorem of Suzuki also assures.

Comment: @markvs Is Suzuki iff? I've only ever seen it stated as self-centralizing of order $p^2$ implies maximal class, never the converse.

Comment: What does Huppert say?

Comment: @markvs He says that Section III.14 comes from Blackburn and Hall, doesn't mention Suzuki at all as far as I can tell. III.14.23 explicitly gives the statement that there's an element with centralizer of order $p^2$ in a maximal-class $p$-group. That would be where he would have mentioned Suzuki if it were iff.

Comment: There should be a proof involving the fact that non-characteristic maximal subgroups of a maximal class group are necessarily maximal class, and that there is a unique normal subgroup of index $p^2$. This limits (to 1) the number of characteristic maximal subgroups of a maximal, maximal-class subgroup, hence it cannot be exceptional. I think one is supposed to use induction and do it for $G/Z(G)$ to force every maximal-class group to have a maximal-class maximal subgroup. I will see if that works tomorrow.

Comment: If Huppert absteins, I am not in a position to argue. Good luck!